# Passing a jQuery load() function variable to codeigniter controller

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

is there a way to pass a variable to a codeigniter controller using jquery's load() function?

currently this is my non working code

main.php

```
<input type="hidden" id="url" name="url" value="<?php echo base_url();?>site/pax_dropdown/" /> 
<input type="hidden" val="2" id="value"> 

<ul id="result" class="dropdown-menu">
    <?php $this->load->view("site/pax_dropdown"); ?>
</ul>
```

pax_dropdown.php

```
<li><a href="">3</a></li>
<li><a href="">4</a></li>
<li><a href="">5</a></li>
<li><a href="">6</a></li>
<li><a href="">7</a></li>
<li><a href="">8</a></li>
<li><a href="">9</a></li>

<?php 
echo $id; 
?>
```

script.js

```
var url = $("#url").val();
var val = $("#value").val();
$('#result').load(url,val);
```

controller

```
public function pax_dropdown($id)
    {
        $data['id'] = $id;
        $this->load->vars($data);
        $this->load->view("site/pax_dropdown"); 
    }
```

with this code the pax_dropdown.php successfully loads inside the

```
<ul id="result">
```

in my main.php however my test variable $id cannot be found and says Message: Undefined variable: id
am i doing something wrong?

---

by the way i also tried sending the variable to the controller this way:

main

```
<input type="hidden" id="url" name="url" value="<?php echo base_url();?>site/pax_dropdown/2" />
```

i placed the variable to be passed at the end of the url, which in this case is "2"

and it still did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this example to pass a variable using `jQuery.load()` :

```
var siteName='example.com';
$("#result").load(sitename+"/site/pax_dropdown/2", {"variableName": variable});
```

Comment: for some weird reason when i placed the url directly inside .load() [i.e:$("#result").load(sitename+"/site/pax_dropdown/2", {"variableName": variable});] instead of storing it in a variable it worked

Comment: mmm it should work even if you put url without variable , anyway happy  to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function(){
    var url = $("#url").val();
    var val = $("#value").val();
    $("#result").load(url, {id: val});
});

function pax_dropdown()
{
    $data['id'] = $this->input->post('id');
    $this->load->vars($data);
    $this->load->view("site/pax_dropdown"); 
}
```

And

```
<ul id="result" class="dropdown-menu">
<?php //$this->load->view("site/pax_dropdown"); comment out this line ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: i tried commenting it out and pax_dropdown no longer appeared in my dropdown-menu

Comment: Try once edited above, Check your console for the post call too and see what response are you getting.

Answer (score -1):

Don't you have a default ID? If so, set this to the $id. If you don't want any default number, just wrap it into an if statement (if (isset($id)) and don't use the $id if it isn't set and logically shouldn't be set.

Maybe the logic behind the code would help as well for finding a solution.

Comment: This should not have been an answer. You are asking more things than explaining. Please use comments for that.

Comment: Ok, I'm new here, sorry. Have to learn how to use it properly.